# Selecting Shapefiles by number of rows using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder

I have several shapefiles in a folder and all of them are points. What I want is to choose those that have more than two records.

I am using the ArcGIS ModelBuilder. I made an iterate feature class and then I made a get count that give me the number of rows for each shapefile. From this step I cannot do anything else. But I think the solution is to use one tool that has a logical condition and so let me just obtain the shapefiles that has more than 2 rows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, use branching logic on the get count variable, here is the If-Then-Else logic for branching logic page:

[Using If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm)